# VIM find all occurrences and replace with input

Tags: vim

Is it possible to search a file for the occurrences of a specific word and ask the user for input to replace this word with. Do the same thing over again, either typing in a new replacement or using something from your history, until all the words are replaced or the user quits. Keep in mind that I want to have the choice to skip over words I don't want to replace.

Just using

```
:%s/value_one/value_two/gc
```

would mean I have to execute this command for each different replacement I have in mind. Is this possible or is there something wrong with this workflow. I would use this when pasting boilerplate code that only need one variable to be changed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
%s/value_one/\=input('replace <'.submatch(0).'> with: ')/gc
```

`:h :s\=` and `:h input()`. You should be able to provide a default value for input if you wish.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Is exactly what I was looking!

Comment: I could be wrong but shouldn't it be : %s/value_one/\=input('replace <'.submatch(0).'> with: ')/gc. Double slash after value_one gives me 'E488: Trailing characters'.

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the perfect, Just sharing what I used.

This assumes that `:set hl` is set already. Pressing `*` would search for the word under cursor. Bring the cursor to your word. But I usually use `gd` instead of `*`.

Then, change it using `ciw` to replacement word. Then `Esc`. We can now go to next occurence by `n`.

If this need to be changed to the same word, then pressing `.` does that.
If not, you can change to new value by using `ciw` again.

If you don't intend to change next occurence, just skip it by pressing `n`, which takes to next occurence.

This seems little manual, but this gives a conservative control over my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I prefer the answer from Luc Hermitte because it's abit more elegant in my opinion. Thanks for the effort though

Comment: Absolutely , no problem. Me too

Comment: You can also use the `gn` motion.  e.g `cgn` then `.` to repeat (No `n`!). For more help see `:h gn` and this Vimcasts episode: [Operating on search matches using gn](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/operating-on-search-matches-using-gn/)